# Creating a list in asp.net mvc without javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a form where the user creates a list and then saves it. The list can have an arbitrary number of rows. The user cannot save the list until it is complete (all rows/items are added) and I cannot use javascript to do it all on the clientside before posting.

The form will create a contact, like in an address book or something. The entity looks like this:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public List<ContactRow> ContactRows { get; set; }
}
```

The ContactRow looks like this:

```
public class ContactRow
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

So, basically it is a contact with a name and a company. The contact has a list of contact rows, where each row has a type (phone, email, etc) and a value (555 - 12334, test@email.com, etc).

My form will contain two ordinary textboxes for Name och Company respectively. But I'm not sure how to handle the list with contact rows. What I want the user to be able to do is adding new rows, editing rows and deleting rows. All this must be done before the save button i clicked, i.e. the list must be all done when saving.

This is not very hard to to with javascript and I've already done that. But now I want to implement this functionality without javascript. It is ok to post to the server while building up the list, but the list cannot be saved until it is done.

Ideas?

Comment: You are going to have very hard time implementing this functionality without javascript. Not that it is impossible but, well, it will be quite a lot of work.

Comment: Agreed, but from an accessibility point of view, it is far better.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use javascript a postback whilst building up the list is all you can do.

This user experience is often deemed poor as work is ongoing, but is the best starting point when using [progressive-enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) to make your application more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

The OP stated Javascript was not an option. I feel your pain as one of our applications had a similar requirement. We have a construct called an **updateable list** with the same functionality as you outlined.

We perform data handling on the server. Each list is displayed in a table. Each row contains the item data and has an action icon associated with it. The default is to display and we support new, updated and deleted actions.

After the user enters data for an item they press a button to add or remove the item from the list. Selecting existing items allows for an update operation. The list, and status, is determined on the server and the client does not run Javascript.

As @rich.kelly pointed out you will need to go to the server for each operation. It takes longer to do anything and your session gets a workout but it meets the client requirements.